# HTML option list information not displaying within PHP echo

Tags: php, html

I've got a set of code I'm trying to move within the `php` tag to leverage 'php' logic features.  I've got most of it working but I'm struggling a bit with an option list I have.  I've looked around the forums but can't seem to find anything close to this.

Here is what my original option list looks like:

```
<div class="plan">
    <label for="g2c3m">Month</label>
        <select id="g2c3m" name="g2c3m">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "1")?"selected" : ""; ?> >1</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "2")?"selected" : ""; ?> >2</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "3")?"selected" : ""; ?> >3</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "4")?"selected" : ""; ?> >4</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "5")?"selected" : ""; ?> >5</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "6")?"selected" : ""; ?> >6</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "7")?"selected" : ""; ?> >7</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "8")?"selected" : ""; ?> >8</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "9")?"selected" : ""; ?> >9</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "10")?"selected" : ""; ?> >10</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "11")?"selected" : ""; ?> >11</option>
        <option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "12")?"selected" : ""; ?> >12</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to transition this `html` based code into `php` based code.   Here's what I've come up with:

```
echo "<div class=\"plan\">";
    echo "<label for=\"g2c3m\">Month</label>";
        echo "<select id=\"g2c3m\" name=\"g2c3m\">";
        echo "<option value=\"\"></option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"1\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >1</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"2\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >2</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"3\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >3</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"4\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >4</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"5\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >5</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"6\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >6</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"7\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >7</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"8\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >8</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"9\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >9</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"10\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >10</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"11\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >11</option>";
        echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"12\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >12</option>";
        echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
```

The option list displays properly, but when I submit the information to the server, it is not echo'd back properly.

I believe I'm following the proper `\` rules regarding the quotes, but it's not working.

What am I missing?  I'd be eternally grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Why?  The first example is so much more readable, but you could definitely improve the repetitiveness by using a loop.  The first example utilizes PHP logic so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here with your rewrite.

Comment: I agree but there are other things I want to do.

Comment: I don't get it.  Both use PHP, the only thing you've accomplished is making it 10x harder to read and work with later on.  The first example is ideal for templating.

Comment: Yes they do, but I can use logics and other php operators on the first.

Comment: @airider74 You can use logic in your first example, as well. Can you mention a specific use case where the second example makes sense?

Comment: It's already using PHP operators and logics...  You can open and close php as much as you need to.

Comment: I'm using if statements to hide the input for these values as well as all the HTML if what they want to input is in the past.  I thought about doing this with javascript initially but since my code already had php in it, I stuck with that since this can all be handled on the server side of things.

Comment: Well I get, that it is really ugly if you have 10 php tags in one line, but neither is that the case here nor would I use echo to avoid that. Either save the contents in variables beforehand (like all classes) and/or use heredoc.

Comment: You can still use `if` statements with your original PHP formatting. Have you tried it?

Comment: You know you can write something like `<?php if($bool) { ?><html>something</html><?php } ?>` and it will only output the html if `$bool` was true?

Comment: and even nicer for longer parts you can use `if($bool):` ... `endif;` and similarly with foreach, for, while etc.

Comment: I've gone down the if($bool) routes but it seemed like even more work....probably because I don't understand it as well as I should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your question but it will help you regardless.

It is perfectly acceptable to open and close PHP code lots of times when writing template code.  PHP can be closed and opened as much as is needed (as long as it's not in the middle of an expression).  So you can run an if statement, close php, print out HTML, then reopen PHP like so:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
    <p>Hello World</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Goodbye World</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or for loops:

```
<?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This uses the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (if/endif, foreach/endforeach) which is great for templating.

Comment: Thanks Devon I'll give this a try.

Comment: I think this is going to work...I'll work on this and let you know

Comment: Devon...this ended up fitting my bill, and with a bit more research on alternative syntax now I feel better equipped for future php use.  I ended up using the syntax "flyingmana" pointed out in the comments section here...http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare one row in both styles:

```
<option <?php echo ($row["g2c3m"] === "1")?"selected" : ""; ?> >1</option>
echo "<option ".$row['g2c3m']." === \"1\")?\"selected\" : \"\"; >1</option>";
```

The first one has a ternary operator (if `$row["g2c3m"] === "1"` then output selected else nothing.

In the second version you do not have that operator. Instead you are outputting the php code.

Correct would be

```
echo "<option ". (($row['g2c3m'] === "1")? "selected" : "" ) . " >1</option>";
```

That way the ternary operator is still evaluated instead of simply output as a string.

Note: I am not 100% certain that a ternary operator can be used like that in-line. You might need multiple lines. Either bei concatenation, using a variable or multiple echos.

Comment: Okay,  let me take a look at this